# XML Data multiple nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml file that all the rest of the nodes depends on the first one. I created a tree diagram to help illustrate it.

[image: XML Data Schema]

The problem I am having is that each node depends on the first one but they do not have any columns that link each other.

Here is the Link to the 
[XML Document](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3EA0B7C27E41C301!7431&authkey=!AFqU0BildNv7-bk&ithint=file%2Cxml)

Here is my sql so far

```
SELECT
        B.RD.query('racedata/todays_cls').value('.','varchar(max)') AS todays_cls,
        B.RD.query('racedata/horsedata/horse_name').value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS horse_name,
        B.RD.query('racedata/horsedata/jockey/jock_disp').value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS jockeyname
        FROM @xmlData.nodes('data') AS B(RD)
```

[image: Updated SQL Query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the second `CROSS APPLY` on the result of the first one, so that you get `<horsedata>` elements that corresponds to current `<racedata>`. See a working demo example below.

**sample data :**

```
declare @xml XML = '
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.trackmaster.com/xmlSchema/ppXMLData.xsd">  
  <racedata> 
    <race>1</race>
    <todays_cls>59</todays_cls>
    <distance>800.0</distance>
    <country>USA</country>  
    <horsedata> 
      <horse_name>BROADWAY KATE</horse_name>
      <owner_name>C. Steve Larue</owner_name>
      <program>1</program>
      <pp>1</pp>
      <weight>121</weight>
    </horsedata> 
    <horsedata> 
      <horse_name>UNFAITHFUL</horse_name>
      <owner_name>Melson, James L., Thomson, Ramona and Connell</owner_name>
      <program>2</program>
      <pp>2</pp>
      <weight>121</weight>
    </horsedata> 
  </racedata> 
  <racedata> 
      <race>2</race>
      <todays_cls>87</todays_cls>
      <distance>800.0</distance>
      <country>USA</country>  
      <horsedata> 
        <horse_name>MAGNETIC START</horse_name>
        <owner_name>Vernon D. Coyle</owner_name>
        <program>1</program>
        <pp>1</pp>
        <weight>121</weight>
      </horsedata>  
      <horsedata> 
        <horse_name>SKI POLE</horse_name>
        <owner_name>Downunder Cable, LLC</owner_name>
        <program>2</program>
        <pp>2</pp>
        <weight>121</weight>
      </horsedata> 
    </racedata>
</data>
'
```

**query :**

```
SELECT 
    rd.value('race[1]', 'int') AS race,
    rd.value('todays_cls[1]','int') AS todays_cls,
    hd.value('pp[1]','int') AS pp,
    hd.value('weight[1]','int') AS weight
FROM @xml.nodes('data/racedata') AS B(RD)
CROSS APPLY RD.nodes('horsedata') AS C(HD)
```

**output :**

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

In response to the updated query, you should've shredded on `horsedata` element level as suggested in the above query, something like this :

```
SELECT
    B.RD.query('todays_cls').value('.','varchar(max)') AS todays_cls,
    C.HD.query('horse_name').value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS horse_name,
    C.HD.query('jockey/jock_disp').value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS jockeyname
FROM @xml.nodes('data/racedata') AS B(RD)
    CROSS APPLY RD.nodes('horsedata') AS C(HD)
```

Comment: your code works however when you add data from Race 2 it does not show as Race 2. I edited my question to show you.

Comment: @DanNick added the second race to sample data, query remains untouched. Still showing the expected output..

Comment: ok I see what I am doing wrong. Add this to the equation: CROSS APPLY RD.nodes('horsedata/jockey') AS D(JD) with a select statement of JD.value('jock_disp[1]','varchar(100)') AS jockey That is when the data shows the wrong information

Comment: @DanNick see **UPDATE** section

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance and patience. I have been working for the past two days on getting this script right.